# Will there be a problem if I request a rewarded video too much?

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob

I want to have a rewarded video loaded all the time so they can be immediately shown when required. I mad the code shown below, so when the load failed, the program will make another request. My issue is I did not expect that this can loop so many times especially if there is no video available. Will there be any problem with admob because of the volume of request. Just checked my admob report just now and my app has requested thousands of request with impression less than ten.

```
public void HandleRewardBasedVideoFailedToLoad(object sender, AdFailedToLoadEventArgs args)
{
    if (!this.rewardBasedVideo.IsLoaded()) {
        this.RequestRewardBasedVideo();
    }

}
```

Comment: Check this out.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55947850/how-to-fix-admob-offline-performance-problem/55948239#55948239

Comment: Thanks. I guess using a coroutine is the best way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can request for a new video if the previous one has failed to load. There is an event "OnAdFailedToLoad" inside rewardedvideo class that you can use. you can assign a listener to that event.

Example:

```
rewardedVideo.OnAdFailedToLoad += HandleRewardedVideoFailedToLoad;

public void HandleRewardedVideoFailedToLoad(object sender, AdFailedToLoadEventArgs args)
{
   this.RequestRewardBasedVideo();
}
```

Let me know if it helps.